# How do I successfully create a drill-down hierarchy of data between three views?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

So far I've successfully  created a drill down hierarchy of data between two table views. My `firstTableView` has the original set of rows, and each row in the firstTableView then segues into the `secondTableView` data specific to that firstTableView row selected.

[image]

To get that data hierarchy, I created a class called `Sport`. Each sport object had a `sportCategory` property which I passed to the secondTableView. Here's the code:

```
class Sport {

    var name: String = "sport name"
    var sportCategories: NSArray = ["variations of selected sport"]

}

let aSport:[Sport] = {
    var basketball = Sport()
    basketball.name = "Basketball"
    basketball.sportCategories = {
        var temp = ["International Basketball","Wheelchair Basketball","Beach Basketball","Deaf Basketball","Dwarf Basketball"]
        temp.sortInPlace(<)
        return temp
        }()

    var golf = Sport()
    golf.name = "Golf"
    golf.sportCategories = {
        var temp = ["Miniature Golf","Dart Golf","Sholf","Disc Golf","Footgolf"]
        temp.sortInPlace(<)
        return temp
        }()

    var football = Sport()
    football.name = "Football"
    football.sportCategories = {
        var temp = ["Flag Football","Indoor Football","Arena Football","Non-Tackle Football","Paper Football"]
        temp.sortInPlace(<)
        return temp
        }()

    var swimming = Sport()
    swimming.name = "Swimming"
    swimming.sportCategories = {
        var temp = ["Competitive Swimming","Synchronized Swimming","Duo Swimming","Relay Swimming"]
        temp.sortInPlace(<)
        return temp
        }()

    return  [basketball,golf,football,swimming]
    }()
```

Now the issue is, each `sportCategory` row from the secondTableView must then segue into **its own collectionView, with its own set of data** specific to that secondTableViewCell row selected. So the order must go

```
firstTableViewCell -> secondTableViewCell -> collectionView
```

My issue is I don't know how to extend the class to pass data to its own collectionView. At the moment each row segues into the same collectionView data:

[image]

So can I pass data from the firstTableView, all the way to the collectionView accordingly, using Swift?

Comment: Your data structure is only two deep: an array of sports that keeps an array of strings (sub-sports).  To get to a third level in the UI, don't you want three-level-deep data?  Those sub-sport strings need to be objects themselves, and they need to keep a collection, like sub-sub-sports.

Comment: How can I make the sub sports objects rather then just strings  so they can house their own collectionView @danh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to imagine how to drill down through a 3 level hierarchy when the data is only a two level hierarchy.  Lets make a three level hierarchy...

```
class Sport {
    var name: String = "sport name"
    var sportCategories: NSArray = ["variations of selected sport"]
}
```

Say the hierarchy is simple (but 3 levels)

```
All Sports
  |
  |
  ----Basketball
         |
         ---- International Basketball
                    |
                    --- Tibetan Basketball
```

So we don't want "International Basketball" to be a string, we want it to be an object, like Basketball is...

```
var tibetanBBall = Sport()
tibetanBBall.name = "Tibetan Basketball"
tibetanBBall.sportCategories = [  ]  // this is a leaf.  it has no kids

var internationalBBall = Sport()
internationalBBall.name = "International Basketball"
internationalBBall.sportCategories = [ tibetanBBall ]  // see? it has kids

var bBall = Sport()
bBall.name = "Basketball"
bBall.sportCategories = [ internationalBBall ]
```

Notice how `sportCategories` is never an array of strings?  It always contains other `Sport` objects.  That's how a hierarchy can get arbitrarily deep.

Now your logic is: when pushing to the next view controller (probably on prepareForSegue.. the question doesn't mention how you initiate the push), pass the selected sport's `sportCategories` to the next vc.

Comment: hm ok I see, that makes sense.